# Can't Accept Answer Through iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Ever the fan of the ironic screenshot, I present to you my inability to accept an answer posted by one of the app developers.

[image]

There is no checkmark. I also tried the sideways ellipsis next to "answered" but that doesn't have anything but "edit"

Am I dense? Or is this missing?

Comment: This feature is indeed missing from the alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I'll accept this answer once the app lets me ;)